# Two button when using NavigationView on 17763

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP Application which uses the NavigationView. Up to now there was a back button in the Titlebar. However, when I set the targetversion to 17763 I have two, one in the Titlebar and one form the NavigationView:

[image]

I tried to collapse the one in the Titlebar, but after the first navigation it appears again. Is there any recommandation which one to use and how can I hide the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigation-history-and-backwards-navigation#system-back-behavior-for-backward-compatibilities) say you should move away from having the back button in the title bar and instead put it in the app UI:

> Previously, UWP apps used AppViewBackButtonVisibility for backwards navigation. The API will continue to be supported to ensure backward compatibility, but we no longer recommend relying on AppViewBackButtonVisibility. Instead, your app should draw its own in-app back button.

The back button can be part of the `NavigationView`. For example the Microsoft Store app now does this as well. The underlying reason for this is the (likely in the future, as it was scratched from current builds) Sets feature, which will basically add tabs in the title bar, so having back button there requires adding a "fake" title bar underneath.

Comment: So when I get that right I should use          "currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Disabled" to disable it, right? Will that work on older version of windows although the disbaled state was only added in 17134?

Comment: Yes, you disable the app view back button and use the `NavigationView` one instead. The back button in this control was introduced in version 1803.

Comment: If you need to support an earlier version, try using the Windows UI library which has backwards compatible versions of the new control features. Also you can just create your own back button, as long as you show and hide properly.

Comment: Check this article for some more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview

Comment: Thanks. I tried the disabled enum. but after the first navigation, the back button appears again. Also the back button of the Navigation view does not activate at any given point. A bit strange.

Comment: I think you must hook it up manually - subscribe to Frame's Navigate event to see when the user navigated and check if you can go back using the CanGoBack property. If yes set the back button visibility in the navigationview. Also the title bar back button should not appear normally. You must have written some code to have it appear. Or are you using some framework which does that?